# Data in custom control not being maintained when user navigates around the application

Tags: xpages

My application uses the Application Control. In the right column of the control itself I put another CC that displays information about the user.

The idea is that as the user moves throughout the app they will always see this info.

The data is displayed on the first view, but not in any of the forms.

The data appears in views, but not in the forms, even though I am able to retrieve the document unid in one field.

The code for the Custom Control is below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" action="openDocument"
            databaseName="TheTruth.nsf" formName="employee">
            <xp:this.documentId><![CDATA[#{javascript:var userName:NotesName = session.createName(session.getEffectiveUserName());
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(), "DATABASE.nsf");
var viewHandle = db.getView("(ViewName)");
var doc:NotesDocument = viewHandle.getDocumentByKey(userName.toString());
return doc.getUniversalID();}]]></xp:this.documentId>
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:panel id="pnlHeader"
        style="width:275.00px;padding-right:30.0px">
        <xe:widgetContainer id="widgetContainerHeader">
            <xp:panel style="padding-top:8.0px;padding-bottom:8.0px">
                <xp:table>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox1"
                                style="width:97.0%;font-weight:bold;font-size:18pt"
                                value="#{document1.HR_FullName}">
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox2"
                                style="width:97.0%" value="#{document1.HR_MarketSegmentText}">
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox3"
                                style="width:97.0%">
                                <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Blank"}]]></xe:this.value>
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox4"
                                style="width:97.0%">
                                <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var userName:NotesName = session.createName(session.getEffectiveUserName());
var db:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(), "DATABASE.nsf");
var viewHandle = db.getView("ViewName");
var doc:NotesDocument = viewHandle.getDocumentByKey(userName.toString());
return doc.getUniversalID();}]]></xe:this.value>
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox5"
                                style="width:97.0%">
                                <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Blank"}]]></xe:this.value>
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox6"
                                style="width:97.0%">
                                <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Blank"}]]></xe:this.value>
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox7"
                                style="width:97.0%">
                                <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Blank"}]]></xe:this.value>
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox8"
                                style="width:97.0%" value="#{document1.HR_OfficePhone}">
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox9"
                                style="width:97.0%" value="#{document1.HR_CellPhone}">
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox10"
                                style="width:97.0%" value="#{document1.HR_DirectDial}">
                            </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                </xp:table>
            </xp:panel>
        </xe:widgetContainer>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your need to set ignoreRequestParams="true". Because that's not set, on XPages that do not have a document passed in the URL, it's showing the document you define. On pages where you open, edit or create a document, the documentId etc are getting overridden by what's in the URL parameters, which explains why you're not seeing the document you expect. ignoreRequestParams on the datasource in your custom control will solve your problem.

Comment: Awesome Paul. It of course worked, PLUS I understand why, which is at least as important. Many many thanks.